# Undo 'dvc add' operation

Tags: dvc

I `dvc add`-ed a file I did not mean to add. I have not yet committed.

How do I undo this operation? In Git, you would do `git rm --cached <filename>`.

To be clear: I want to make DVC forget about the file, and I want the file to remain untouched in my working tree. This is the opposite of what `dvc remove` does.

One [issue](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/1524) on the DVC issue tracker suggests that `dvc unprotect` is the right command. But reading the [manual page](https://dvc.org/doc/commands-reference/unprotect) suggests otherwise.

Is this possible with DVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per mroutis on the DVC Discord server:

1. `dvc unprotect` the file; this won't be necessary if you don't use `symlink` or `hardlink` caching, but it can't hurt.
2. Remove the .dvc file
3. If you need to delete the cache entry itself, run `dvc gc`, or look up the MD5 in `data.dvc` and manually remove it from `.dvc/cache`.

*Edit* -- there is now an issue on their Github page to add this to the manual: https://github.com/iterative/dvc.org/issues/625

Comment: Yep. Basically `rm -f <filename>; dvc gc`

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel the goal was to keep the original file intact while "un-tracking" it with DVC.

Comment: My bad, I meant `rm -f <filename.dvc>; dvc gc`.

Comment: Also, `rm -f <filename.dvc>` doesn't remove the file from `.gitignore`, so Git will still think that the file doesn't exist. If you've not made any other changes to it then you may also want to `git restore .gitignore` as well.

Comment: @IBBoard good point. It might not be in the top-level gitignore either, so it might be better to `grep -R '<filename>' **/.gitignore` for it and change those files accordingly.

Comment: From my tests just now, `dvc remove file.ext.dvc` appears to leave the file in the working directory (at least for uncommitted files). Saves a lot of messing with git ignore files!

Answer (score 2):

`dvc remove` appears to do what you need for uncommitted files - at least for files that aren't in a pipeline. The key (which wasn't clear to me from the error or the docs) is to pass the `….dvc` file name, otherwise it tries to find and remove it as a section from `dvc.yaml`.

```
# Precondition: DVC is configured for the repo. No dvc.yaml file (untested with it)
$ touch so-57966851.txt
$ dvc add so-57966851.txt
WARNING: 'so-57966851.txt' is empty.                                                                                                                          
100% Adding...|████████████████████████████████████████|1/1 [00:00, 49.98file/s]
                                                                                                                                                              
To track the changes with git, run:

    git add .gitignore so-57966851.txt.dvc
# Ooops! I did the wrong thing! I didn't mean to add that…
$ dvc remove so-57966851.txt.dvc
$ ll so-*.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ibboard users 0 Aug 23 20:27 so-57966851.txt
```

(Tested with v2.5.4)